# I am reading the book "Introduction to java programming and Data Structure" In the chapter which explains Class Abstraction and Encapsulation it says:

Tags: java, class, oop

"The creator of a class describes the functions of the class and
lets the user know how the class can be used. The collection of public constructors, methods, and fields that are accessible from outside the class, together with the description of
how these members are expected to behave, serves as the class’s contract. "

**What is the Class Contract ?**
**I Need anyone to explain this paragraph to me**

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about it?

Comment: What don't you understand about the statement?

Comment: There is a lot of fluff. Try "public constructors, methods, and fields" ... "serve as the class’s contract." The description (if there is one) maybe full of falsehoods (or half-truths). But the stuff you can call is the stuff that makes up the class's contract.

Comment: The [Java™ Platform, Standard Edition API Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html) is an example of the contract between the developers of Java and the Java users (developers).  For a given class, you are provided a list of the public constructors and methods you may use.

Answer (score 0):

> *"The creator of a class describes the functions of the class and lets the user know how the class can be used. The collection of public constructors, methods, and fields that are accessible from outside the class, together with the description of how these members are expected to behave, serves as the class’s contract."*

> What is the Class Contract?

Literally ... it is the "The collection of public constructors, methods, and fields that are accessible from outside the class, together with the description of how these members are expected to behave ..."

Those things constitute the things that a user of the class *should* be able to depend on; i.e. the things about the class that *won't be changed* ...

This notion of "contract" relates to [Design by Contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) as originally described by Bertrand Meyer in the 1980's.

It is an *analog* of a [legal contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract).

---

Now ... obviously ... someone *could* change the class in ways that mean that the contract is broken.  They can rename or remove methods, change argument or result types, change the way that the methods work in *contradiction* of the javadocs.

But the consequences of breaking the contract are likely to be bad for code that uses the API.  It may stop working.  It may fail to compile.  And note that it may not be *your* code that breaks.